# How to mount Apple's SuperDrive in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, mount, dvd

Maybe it sounds strange to use a USB CD-Drive nowadays. However, I need to get an old data from a CD and the only available CD-Drive was my old Apple's SuperDrive. Thus, I did the following steps:

1. First connect the SuperDrive.
2. Then, install the `sg3-utils` by:

   ```bash
   $ sudo apt-get install sg3-utils
   ```
3. Then, to identify where the SuperDrive is use:

   ```bash
   $ ls -lt | less | grep sr

    brw-rw----+ 1 root  cdrom      11,   1 jun 26 09:55 sr1
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root             3 jun 26 09:32 cdrw -> sr0
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root             3 jun 26 09:32 dvdrw -> sr0
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root             3 jun 26 09:32 cdrom -> sr0
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root             3 jun 26 09:32 dvd -> sr0
    brw-rw----+ 1 root  cdrom      11,   0 jun 26 09:32 sr0
   ```

   choose that with a **b** in the details of file, in my case is `sr1`
4. Then you need to have a CD or DVD ready on the device, **please do not push the CD if you try it the Drive will not allowed**, the send this code to initialize the Super Drive

   ```bash
   $ sg_raw /dev/sr1 EA 00 00 00 00 00 01
   ```

   and magically the SuperDrive will introduce the CD and the drive can be used.

However, this procedure has to be repeated after you boot the system again.

**Is there a method or procedure to do it easier ?**

Answer (score 6):

You can create a udev rule file to run this automatically. Create this as `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-mac-superdrive.rules`:

```
#
# Apple SuperDrive initialization rule
#
# See: https://gist.github.com/yookoala/818c1ff057e3d965980b7fd3bf8f77a6

ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1500", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05ac", DRIVERS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/sg_raw %r/sr%n EA 00 00 00 00 00 01"
```

Read for detailed explaination: https://gist.github.com/yookoala/818c1ff057e3d965980b7fd3bf8f77a6

Comment: This worked for me on Pop_OS! 22.04, but only after I unplugged and re-plugged the drive. Sorta obvious, but wanted to post this in case a novice runs across your fantastic answer.