Install Drivers for Internal Superdrive (DVD/CD) Intel Mac 2008 Ubuntu 22.04
as above, I have working install of ubuntu 22 on early 2008 iMac; ran a script to get the broadcom wireless going, so wondering if there is a similar procedure for allowing Linux systems to recognize the internal dvd/cd drive for ripping and writing. tia

Try this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1348356/380067 , I'm not entirely sure that applies to internal DVD drives but it's worth a shot
